# Swift: Animating button parameters (inset, font size, etc...)

Tags: ios, swift, animation, transform

I'm trying to access and animate different parameters for my buttons.
They're by default set in Interface Builder with a set font size, alignment and insets, and I'd like to access those parameters and change them with an animation when the button is triggered : when my button is not clicked (by default), its title has a smaller font size, it's aligned bottom left and with some title insets ; when I click it I want the font to be bigger, set the insets to 0 and alignment to center (both horizontally and vertically), and this transition to be animated.
How do I build the function to access and animate those parameters ?

```
@IBOutlet weak var circlePad: UIButton!
@IBAction func padPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        animatePadTitle(circlePad)
    }

func animatePadTitle(button: UIButton) {
        // not sure how to tackle this here, do I use something like button.transform = CGAffineTransform ?
    }
```

Thanks

EDIT: I tried a bit more to mess with parameters and "upgraded" my function to this :

```
func animatePadTitle(button: UIButton, insetBottom: Int, insetLeft: Int, fontSize: CGFloat, alignVert: UIControl.ContentVerticalAlignment, alignHor: UIControl.ContentHorizontalAlignment) {
       // button.transform = CGAffineTransform
        button.titleEdgeInsets.bottom = CGFloat(insetBottom)
        button.titleEdgeInsets.left = CGFloat(insetLeft)
        button.contentVerticalAlignment = alignVert
        button.contentHorizontalAlignment = alignHor
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: fontName, size: fontSize)
        
    }
```

The question is now how to animate the transition between those parameters every time I click on the button ?
I did set a bool to check if the pad is lit, and in an if condition I wrote my function with different parameters and the changes occur, just they're abrupt and I'd like them to be smoother.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CGAffineTransform scale function to scale up or down the overall bounds of the button including the title.

To scale up use > 1,
To scale down use < 1

```
 @objc func animatePadTitle() {
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.15,
               animations: { [weak self] in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                self.circlePad.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.1, y: 1.1)
               },
               completion: { _ in
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.15) {
                  self.circlePad.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                }
             })
            }
```

Comment: thanks Pratheesh, but in my case it's a bit more complex than that : I have a background image for my buttons, and I'm making the title appear on the bottom left of that background image by default, with a small font, then when I click on my button the title is scaled up and centered, with insets removed. I did set insets because there is as well my background image that changes when the button is clicked, and as I created a neumorphic design for it to blend with the background of my view, I needed some insets for the title of the 2 images otherwise bottom left align seemed out of frame

Comment: so if I scale the overall button, it'll scale my background images as well ; also, I have an other button in my view controller that triggers images instead of text on my pad buttons ; so if I do it your way the images will be scaled as well when they are triggered I think. So I think in my case, as my buttons are "complex" it would mess everything up if I scale the overall frame, I was hoping there's a way to just animate smoothly the transitions of the values set for my insets, font size and alignment.

Comment: Hope you tried setting the insets in an animation block. Did that work?